# How to declare rows literal with specific column names in pl/pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to declare an array varible `bkgws` for table `gangwei` with a subset column names `col1` and `col2`, here is what I try:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
    bkgws gangwei(col1, col2)[] := {('fo1','bar1'),('fo2','bar2')}; -- here, syntax error
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO gangwei (config_id, col1, col2) SELECT 1, col1, col2 FROM unnest(bkgws);
END;$$;
```

provided`gangwei`'s all columns are `id, config_id, col1, col2`.

the literal `('fo1','bar1'),('fo2','bar2')` is built from app layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create composite type before by command `CREATE TYPE AS`

```
CREATE TYPE gangwei AS (col1 varchar, col2 varchar);

DO $$
DECLARE
  bkgws gangwei[] DEFAULT '{"(foo, bar)", "(foo2, bar2)"}';
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT * FROM unnest(bkgws)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '% %', r.col1, r.col2;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
 
NOTICE:  foo  bar
NOTICE:  foo2  bar2
DO
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the column names when you `unpack` the array:

```
... FROM unnest(bkgws) AS arr(col1,col2)
```